# QueryParams Not Working With Angular2 Router v 3.4.10

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

With Router V 3.0.0 I can do this

```
this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.queryParams["someParameter"];
```

Bu I can't achieve the same with Router V 3.4.10.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Write in constructor of the component

`constructor(private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        this.route.queryParams.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let someParameter = params['someParameter'];
             console.log(someParameter);
        });
    }`